# Hyper-V Generic Failure + Ubuntu error 0x8007023e on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, hyper-v, wsl2

I've been experiencing some problems with running Ubuntu 20.04 as a distribution of Windows Subsystem on Linux. I want to run it as a virtual machine on Hyper-V. I'm rather new to this, so I'm not sure if I'm even understanding the set up right, but here's what I aim to do:

Run C++ code meant for numerical computations of electromagnetic fields that contains optimizer indicators from Intel's High Performance Computing Toolkit on Linux.

Here is my computer information:

1. Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
2. Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.9 GB usable)
3. NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 GPU
4. 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
5. No pen or touch input is available for this display
6. Windows 10 Pro - Version    20H2
7. OS build    19042.1202

However, I encounter the following struggles:

When trying to Quick Create a VM on Hyper-V, I encounter the error "Generic Failure." This was not the case before I went into BIOS and enabled virtualization - it worked fine then, though the VMs could not access Internet.

I have wsl.exe installed on my computer, and trying to run it results in a terminal flashing for a fraction of a second before it disappears and nothing happens. Then, I try to run the Ubuntu app I installed through the Microsoft store, and it shows:

[WslRegisterDistribution seems to have failed in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcgM9.png)

I tried calling Microsoft and I told them the error code to which they responded by hanging up on me. The GitHub on which this error was posted does not seem to have yielded any actual solutions to the issue on my computer.

What do I do?

Comment: So.. this is all opinion (up front).  If you don't need interoperability between windows and linux, you don't need WSL (which I love).  For this case.. I myself use VirtualBox VMs and have much better luck and (visual) performance than I do with hyper-v.  Again, I love WSL but if you don't need both OSs running as one, VirtualBox is much easier to manage and when full screen.. you won't even know that windows is running in the bkgrnd.  I use WSL to write Linux code and debug it from windows and I love it.. depends on what you need.

Comment: I remember using Virtual Box to run Windows 95 and Windows 98 for fun, but now that doesn't seem to work either when creating an Ubuntu machine. I'm convinced I screwed my computer up somehow because the Ubuntu command line says I'm missing a feature.

Comment: 0x8007nnnn are windows errors in an HResult. The `nnnn` is the Windows' error. The Windows' error is `ERROR_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION 574 (0x23E) 
{Application Error} The exception %s (0x%08lx) occurred in the application at location 0x%08lx.`

Comment: @user1292580 what does the location 0x%08lx mean? I found "0x is a string prefix that would notify the user that it is an hexadecimal, while %08lx is the actual placeholder for a long int ( l ) converted to hexadecimal ( x ) with a padding of 8 zeroes ( 08 )." Does this point to anything specific?

Comment: The error message says nothing specific because the program that crashed didn't fill in the information. `0x%08lx` the program is supposed to fill actual information for the place holder. If you know the app then attach a debugger to get the info. Although this is very advanced. See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/brief-introduction-to-windows-debugger.html